# Getting video source continuously one after another in one video tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new for JavaScript and JQuery pleas help me how to play array of videos 
    continuously in video player when i click on  a button.How to write a logic to getting 
    videourls of the playlist continuously .
    thanks in advance.

```
SourceCode:

start.html
<div class="videoplayer"  id="mainvideoplayer">
<div><input type="button" name="play" id="playAll" value="Play"/></div>
</div>

test.js
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = {
           "playlist": [
                         {
                        "videoName": "Video1",
                        "videoUrl": "videos/alu_blech_en.mp4"
                         },
                         {
                        "videoName": "Video2",
                        "videoUrl": "videos/wm30.mp4"
                         },
                         {
                        "videoName": "Video3",
                        "videoUrl": "videos/sample1.mp4"
                         },
                      ]
           };
    var video = $("<video class='item_video'  id='player' autoplay controls >");
    $("#mainvideoplayer").append(video);
    for (var i in data.playlist) {
                  var ele = $("<input type='checkbox' class='links'
                             id= \"" +data.playlist[i].videoName+ "\"
                            value=\""+data.playlist[i].videoUrl+"\">"
                            +data.playlist[i].videoName+"<br />");
                            $(".playlist-detail").append(ele);    
                                 }
    $("#playAll").click(function(event){
     $("#player").attr("src",play[0].link);
      });

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this... Easy way

```
    $("#playAll").click(function(event){
   var getvideo = document.getElementById('player');
    var videosource = new Array();
    for(i=0;i<data.playlist.length;i++){
    videosource[i] = data.playlist[i].videoUrl;

   }
    getvideo.setAttribute('src', videosource[0]);
    getvideo.play();

    getvideo.addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    function myHandler() {
        i++;
        getvideo.setAttribute('src', videosource[i]);
        getvideo.play();

    }
})
```